# Both Vertical slide and Horizontal slide using Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

I want to include both vertical slide and horizontal slide using owl carousel in same page.Here is my reference code.Issue is only one slide is working,if we implement both in same file

```
<-----------Vertical slide------------>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var owl = jQuery('.owl-carousel');
  owl.owlCarousel({
    autoplay: true,
    items: 1,
    nav: true,
    loop: true,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    animateOut: 'slideOutUp',
    animateIn: 'slideInUp',
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    autoplayHoverPause: false,
   });

  });
  </script>

 <-----------Horizontal slide---------------------->
 <script>
 jQuery('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
 loop: true,
 margin: 10,
 nav: true,
 navText: [
 "<i class='fa fa-caret-left'></i>",
 "<i class='fa fa-caret-right'></i>"
 ],
autoplay: true,
autoplayHoverPause: true,
responsive: {
0: {
  items: 1
},
600: {
  items: 3
},
1000: {
  items: 5
 }
 }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Do share some of the code you have done so far.

Comment: I have added below

Comment: Yeah i Changed and updated